# Count open pull requests and issues on GitHub

Tags: github, github-api

I like to count all open pull requests and issues in a repository with help of the GitHub API. I found out that the API endpoint `/repos/:owner/:repo` result contains a `open_issues` property. However this is the sum of the amount of issues and pull requests.

Is there a way to get or calculate the amount of open issue and pull requersts in a repository?

Comment: Can you iterate over the open issues returned from https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository passing in `state=open`

Comment: `state=open` is the default for both listing issues and pull requests, so it's not necessary to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

osowskit is correct, the easiest way to do this is to iterate over the list of issues and the list of pull requests in a repository (I'm assuming you would like to get separate counts for each, reading between the lines of your question).

The issues API will return both issues and pull requests, so you will need to count both and subtract the number of pull requests from the number of issues to get the count of issues that aren't also pull requests. For example, using the wonderful `github3.py` Python library:

```
import github3

gh = github3.login(token='your_api_token')

issues_count = len(list(gh.repository('owner', 'repo').issues()))
pulls_count = len(list(gh.repository('owner', 'repo').pull_requests()))

print('{} issues, {} pull requests'.format(issues_count - pulls_count, pulls_count))
```

Comment: I hoped GitHub provide a better way to do this. Because iterating over let's say 10.000 issues feels a little bit stupid and not efficient :-/ But thanks anyway!

Comment: Another question just popped up in my mind. GitHub provide issues and pull requests paginated. In that case, the amount of items per page + the amount of items on the last page is the total right?

Comment: Yes, assuming you aren't using a library that handles the pagination automatically (`github3.py` does).

Answer (score 4):

A more efficient way (than the accepted answer) is to use the search API.
To get the number of open issues you can call (replace with your org and repo):

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:realm/realm-java%20is:issue%20is:open&per_page=1
```

and to get the number of PR's:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:realm/realm-java%20is:pr%20is:open&per_page=1
```

You can of course remove `is:open` if you want both open and closed issues/pr's.

Both will return "total_count" with the result. Note that I added `per_page=1` to not actually retrieve all the issues.

Comment: ^^This is the most practical answer.

Answer (score 2):

With [Github Graphql API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), you can now do this in one single request:

```json
{
  repository(owner: "mui-org", name: "material-ui") {
    issues(states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
    }
    pullRequests(states: OPEN) {
      totalCount
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "issues": {
        "totalCount": 471
      },
      "pullRequests": {
        "totalCount": 47
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate over all pull requests. The GitHub API returns pages and in the link header, you have access to the first, previous, next and last pages. You can use that to implement a more efficient algorithm:

1) Fetch the first page and specify a page size of 1
2) Get the value of the last page link (i.e. the number of pages)
3) You will thereby have the number of pages, hence of PRs and will not have to fetch all of these pages.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering, the accepted answer of constructing a search query with the Github Search API can take an is:merged argument instead of is:open, even though that option isn't well documented in the Github API:

For example:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:realm/realm-java%20is:issue%20is:merged&per_page=1
```